# Change color of a group in Sketch?

Tags: color, layers, sketch-app

Is it possible to change the color of all elements in a group?

Currently I have to select each layer in the group to change the color. I wonder if there is a faster way, to achive a color change of grouped layers.

Comment: Ungroup, keeping all selected, change color, and then group?

Comment: What kind of color do you want to change ? Are they text, background , both ?

Comment: Depending on the issue, I would either control+drag over the visuals to select layers directly(and not the group), or work with more symbols (including color symbols) or shared styles, so I can apply one change to more than one object at a time. If you give me a concrete example, I can write a more exhaustive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Still a newbie and learning myself but I found a way around this by using a set style. That way I can select all the lines/layers and apply the style in one click.

For example, I can easily change my line art to white with a 1px line and no fill. It's easy to change the style if you need to make an update.

[image: this screenshot shows the three styles I am working with - blue, gray and white]

My next step is creating a symbol from this icon and creating multiple symbols one for each color that I need.[image: example of setting the style on an icon]

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue today.
Fortunately, my **elements are all the same color** (but separate on different artboards).

My way is:

- *Edit > Find and Replace Color...*
- Choose your *Find color*.
- Choose your *Replace color*.
- Tap *Replace* button.
- Color changed!

[Video with steps.](https://qareplay.com/replay?id=bEUCJY19Qcu12ECI6f0DUJXcR)

Comment: Hi Chu and welcome to the site. I've taken the liberty to edit the formatting of your answer to make it a little easier to read. I've changed your chain of actions to a bulleted list. Normally the > character is used to indicate submenus and as far as I can see, you only need it in the first bullet. I've also put all names of menus and buttons in italic instead of quotes, wrapped the url in a named link and removed the "Cheers!" as we want questions and answers to be as concise as possible. Feel free to revert my changes or edit further if I misunderstood something. 

Comment: Hi Wolff, it looks better now. Thanks for your advice!